# vba excel how to paste values only without cell format

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to use the PasteSpecial but it throws an error - "Expected end of statement"

There is my code.
Thanks

```
LastRow = sheet.Cells(sheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
sheet.Range("A2:S" & LastRow).Select

Selection.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("PT"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Selection.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("AMD"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Selection.AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("201701", "201702", "201703", "201704", "201705", "201706", "201707", "201708", "201709", "201710", "201711", "201712", "201801", "201802", "201803"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Set rng = sheet.Range("A3:A" & LastRow, "B3:B" & LastRow)

rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy MasterWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count, "B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: *VBA* wants the **Copy** to be a separate statement the *precedes* the **PasteSpecial**

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: See JoeBerg's answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to swap your last line of code with this:

```
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
MasterWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count, "B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: It only takes a quick Google search to find out - there's a ton of easy accessible information about Excel VBA coding. Consider browsing google a bit more ;)

But here it is:

`Application.CutCopyMode=False`

Comment: Actually I already got that done with a google search ;). However thanks